# Как сделать такой повторяющийся css-grid?

Tags: css, css-grid, grid

Как сделать такую сетку для неограниченного числа элементов, чтобы не прописывать стили для каждого элемента по очереди :nth-child(1), :nth-child(2) и т.д.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); 
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.item {
  font-size: 3rem;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 1fr;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: 1/3
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.item:nth-child(6) {
  grid-row: 3/5;
}

.item:nth-child(7) {
  grid-row: 3/4;
}

.item:nth-child(8) {
  grid-row: 4/5;
}

.item:nth-child(9) {
  grid-row: 3/5;
}

.item:nth-child(10) {
  grid-row: 5/6;
}
.item:nth-child(11) {
  grid-row: 6/7;
}

.item:nth-child(12) {
  grid-row: 5/7;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
</div>
```